# Multiselect deselect last item after each submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

Multiselect decrease after each `$_POST` submit but all index of ajax response are returned. In this form, I have an event that triggers a change in **Empresa** that loads all the other fields and marks the options that are in the php session returned by ajax.

After each submit, I have all items of session but always last item on each field are deselected.

```
// This code triggers an action in Empresa ...
$(function($) {$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');});

$.ajax({
    url: '/ajaxrequests/requestservicos',
    type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
    data: {empresas:empresas},
    success: function(retorno){
        var servs = retorno.servicos; // [10, 12, 14, 20, 21, 23, 25, 29, 32, 33, 38]
        var checks = retorno.check; // [10, 12, 14, 20, 21, 23, 25]
        console.log(retorno);
        $('#ajax_servico').html("");
        $.each(servs, function(valor, chave){
            $('#ajax_servico').append($('<option>', {
                value: valor,
                text : chave,
                checked: checks[valor],
                selected: checks[valor]
            }));
        });
        $("#ajax_servico").multiselect('destroy');
        MultiselectSet($("#ajax_servico"));
    }
});         

function MultiselectSet(input){
    $(input).multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        nSelectedText: 'selecionados ..',
        nonSelectedText:'Nenhum selecionado ..',
        allSelectedText: 'Todos selecionados ..',
        selectAllText: 'Selecionar todos ..',
        numberDisplayed: 1,
    });
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do here but if you want all items in servico that are in checks to be selected you could try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajaxrequests/requestservicos',
  type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
  data: {empresas:empresas},
})
.then(
  function(retorno){
    const servs = retorno.servicos, // [10, 12, 14, 20, 21, 23, 25, 29, 32, 33, 38]
    checks = retorno.check, // [10, 12, 14, 20, 21, 23, 25]
    $servico = $('#ajax_servico');
    console.log(retorno);
    $servico.html("");
    servs.forEach(function(chave,index){
      const isInChecks = checks.indexOf(chave)!==-1;
      $servico.append($('<option>', {
        value: index,
        text : chave,
        checked: isInChecks,
        selected: isInChecks
      }));      
    });
    $("#ajax_servico").multiselect('destroy');
    MultiselectSet($("#ajax_servico"));
  }
  ,function(reject){console.error("something went wrong:",reject)}
);
```

I'm not sure why you would set the value of the option to the index of the array, would it not be better to set it to the id of what the item is in the database? You set the text of the option to a number, is that the id? If so you should probably set the value to the id and the text to a text value that represents that id in the database.

Comment: If I try to execute your code, I have um error: jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot convert undefined or null to object TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object .. help me with this error.